# JAVA_HOME and PATH environment variable not working in UBUNTU

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, environment-variables

I have downloaded *jdk-7u9-linux-i586.rpm* from oracle. Then I installed it in my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Then I set the environment path as :

```
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/<the jdk directory I cant recall now>
 export PATH={$PATH}:{$JAVA_HOME}/bin
```

Then I checked by `echo $PATH` and `echo $JAVA_HOME`.
Now it is showing correct paths.

BUT THE PROBLEM IS : IF I TRY `java` IN THE CONSOLE IT IS SHOWING UNRECOGNIZED COMMAND ERROR.

Please help me.

Comment: Sorry, it it usr/java/<java directory>/bin.
and it is there for sure, I have checked.

Comment: shouting wouldn't get you answers any faster than they usually do.

Comment: try: `export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin` but before that try `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version`

Comment: what is the output ` ls -l $JAVA_HOME/bin/java`?

Comment: It will help you !! 
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-java_home-path-variable/

Comment: Maybe you should edit the file /etc/environment, and add you path there.

Answer (score 2):

You changed your PATH, but did you re-source and refresh your PATH cache ? (see [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/bash-shell-builtin-commands/) for more details, and check section 3)

e.g.

```
$ vi ~/.profile
$ . ~/.profile
$ echo $PATH # is this right ?
```

and a possible hash

```
$ hash
```

Comment: Everytime I echo $PATH, I get the path to my jdk's bin directory.
But "java" does not work directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply call `export` in a shell, you will set the variables exactly for this one environment. If you want those variables to be there for all shell environments, add them to your `~/.bashrc` or your `~/.profile` files.

EDIT: I think, using a RedHat-specific packages (`.rpm`) on Ubuntu may be a cause of your issue - this is a rather wild guess though. You could either remove your current installation and try a different package, or better yet, install java [using your regular packgage manager](http://thedaneshproject.com/posts/how-to-install-java-7-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java 
apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Comment: I get the actual path to the bin directory of jdk if I echo $PATH.
But the executable does not work directly, works only if I specify the full path. 
Ex. : /usr/java/<jdk path>/bin/java

Comment: @AryasindhuSahu this is very strange. I cannot image how this could happen. As you seem to have double-checked the path in question, I would reinstall the JDK using a regular package manager and try again.

Comment: I could have installed it from console also, but I needed a copy of the jdk for future requirements. So I downloaded that.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it.
It was all my mistake. I have set the **PATH** variable in the */etc/environment* file and it was set wrongly. I set it upto jdk folder and not /bin after that.

After changing it to **bin**, I logged out and logged in again.
Now it is working fine.

Sorry guys for wasting your time and efforts.